# resource busy or locked when installing APIConnect via NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, apiconnect

I get some error message when installing APIConnect from NPM.

I started with a clean install of node.js, v 4.5.0 and made sure NPM is version 3.x.x, in fact it is version 3.3.8.

My laptop using Windows 10.

Before I started the installation, I installed windows-build-tools, https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools

The error message I get is, 
[image]

I install via CMD and run as Administrator.

After this message, I get loads of error messages saying "no such file found" and all of the refer to the directory .staging.

In the end, the last messages says, Maximum call stack size exceeded.

I would really appreciate if anybody could help me.

Comment: I give up on this, node.js and npm stuff. :-)

Answer (score 1):

May be related to this: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11265    If you revert to npm 2 node 4.x comes with default npm 2.x , and if this works for you.    and  try install with --no-optional

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think tough it was related to a breaking change in sqlite 3.1.5 that prevented global installations. The guys at stronglopp, apiconnect installs strongloop/loopback fixed that yesterday, now the install sqlite 3.1.6 and it seemed to work, but I run into another issue now. File paths to long. :-)

Comment: Tested event this, id does not work. I tested to install 32 bits node.js as well, did not work. F**k this. I hate this npm now.

Comment: with sqlite  fixed, you can update to npm 3.10.8, and it should solve your windows path issue.  I actually tried it and it worked for me.

Comment: Which version of apiconnect are you trying to install. The apiconnect on  npmjs.org  v5040,-may still need work around please check out this as well.   https://developer.ibm.com/apiconnect/2016/09/29/installing-apiconnect-on-windows-7-with-ibm-sdk-node-js/

Comment: I have tried "all" possible combination after reading this: https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#compiling-native-addon-modules

After it worked with sqlite, I had this problem with long paths, I think it was solved by enable ntfs long path file names in Windows registry.

After that I had some problem with compiling node add-ons, so I reinstalled Visual Studio Community.

The I had problem with spawn-syn, so I uninstalled everything and manually installed spawn-syn.

After that it worked.

Comment: The link you provided to is another method, should I start over again, uninstall everything and do it your way?

Comment: good for you!!  then after all these hurdle with the environment. :-)

Comment: Ha ha, I have learned a lot and going to write my own answer on this later. But I really liked your link and going to do it that way instead.